# Can't get .mp3 cover via QMediaPlayer (empty string)

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

I'm developing a program that plays music from VK.com social network. The project is almost completed, but there is a small detail: I would like to add support for the music covers. Actually, the problem is as follows: I use **QMediaPlayer** and **QMediaMetaData** to obtain information about a loaded MP3 file. I can get every tag with no problems, except for the album cover tag that I needs. Here is sample code that displays all available tags in the console:

```
void MainWindow::playerMetaDataChanged()
{
    qDebug() << " ";
    qDebug() << "AvailableMetaData:";
    qDebug() << " ";
    QStringList metaData = player->availableMetaData();
    foreach (QString metaDataType, metaData) {
        qDebug() << "Type of metadata: " + metaDataType;
        qDebug() << player->metaData(metaDataType);
        qDebug() << "---------------";
    }
    qDebug() << " ";
}
```

And here is the console output:

```
AvailableMetaData:

"Type of metadata: AlbumArtist"
QVariant(QString, "Within Temptation")
---------------
"Type of metadata: Author"
QVariant(QString, "Daniel Gibson & Robert Westerholt")
---------------
"Type of metadata: MediaType"
QVariant(QString, "Symphonic Gothic Metal")
---------------
"Type of metadata: PosterUrl"
QVariant(QString, "")
---------------
"Type of metadata: Title"
QVariant(QString, "Empty Eyes (Bonus Track)")
---------------
```

As you can see, PosterUrl returns an empty string, although my mp3 file contains album art - I'm sure about it. I was trying to get some other metadata, for example, this:

```
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::PosterUrl);
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::PosterImage);
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::CoverArtImage);
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::CoverArtUrlSmall);
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::CoverArtUrlLarge);
qDebug()<< player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::CoverArtUrlLarge);
```

But every time I get an **QVariant(Invalid)** or **QVariant(QString, "")** message in console. Any ideas to fix that problem?

Comment: What does `isMetaDataAvailable()` returns? I have the same problem for video files and I think it is not well implemented by Qt yet...

Comment: @AlexisP. It returns a bool value if there is one or more tags available. Usually it always returns "true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not fix this issue with `QMediaPlayer`. It has limited tags support. I had the same problem a while ago. The only solution - use [taglib](https://taglib.github.io/) for implement working with tags.